# retain mutable array values after navigating away from view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am new to objective-c and trying to understand better why the following is occurring... in my view controller, I have this in viewDidLoad:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self createProjectData];
}
```

And then:

```
- (void)createProjectData
{
     if(!self.projectData)  {
    self.projectData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:tempProjectInfo1, tempProjectInfo2, nil];
}
```

projectData is a public property:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *projectData;
```

My problem is that when I navigate to a different View Controller and return to this one, projectData is null even though I had initialized previously with the above values... so I'm really hoping someone can explain how I can retain the property value so when I return it has all of the items that I had added to the mutable array.

Comment: Don't recreate this view controller -- use the one you created previously.

Comment: When you leave the view controller, it (along with its properties) is deallocated. That's why `projectData` is `nil` after you leave the view controller and come back to it.  (Note that if you're using a navigation controller and you push `viewController2` from `viewController1` then pop back to `viewController1`, `viewController1`'s properties will still be intact since navigation controllers keep the stack operational.)

Comment: You need to describe how you're moving from one view controller to the other. If you either use a navigation controller, or present the second controller modally, you shouldn't lose any data from the first controller (assuming you're going back correctly).

Comment: I am using a Push segue as part of a Navigation Controller but it sounds like, from these comments, that is not the best approach. What I am trying to do is leave VC1, enter project information on VC2, and then return to VC1 at which point I will add the new project to the mutable array.

Answer (score -1):

Check if somewhere inside  `viewDidDisappear` your code is niling your array.

You may also have code for dealing with memory warnings doing  something similar